# Have a form field stay visible after a submit

Tags: php, javascript, html, webforms

I'll try to be clear. I have a listbox with 3 entries in it, and when my entry number 2 is selected it makes a field, which is by default hidden, become visible.

Then after the form is submitted, the selected item stays in the listbox (already worked that out), but the field that became visible goes back to its default setting, hidden. I'd like it to stay visible, in case the submit didn't pass the validation requirements or whatever other reason.

I know it has to be quite easy but I'm still getting used to HTML/PHP/Javascript.

If you guys need any code parts I'll be more than happy to offer them. I just don't want to post my full code for no reason, which is pretty messy and quite long.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

actually i just found it. thanks for the help, putted me on the right track

so heres the code, you just have to put this anywhere in the body tag.

this will do any action onload.
so as my code goes it will check if the id of my list box is the number 2, if it is its gonna do the actons in the IF statement.
looks for my fields and put them visible.

```
<script>   
window.onload = function() {     
if (document.getElementById("topic2").value=="2")
{
document.getElementById("Agence").style.visibility='Visible';
document.getElementById("agence_tittle").style.visibility='Visible';
}

} 
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using javascript or PHP to show the hidden field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is your form submit function refreshing the page or setting hidden fields/classes back to hidden?

Comment: yes when i submit, it does refresh the page,

but i thought that was a normal behavior.

Comment: jsut guessing here, but the refresh is maybe reloading your default css, which makes the field hidden again.  You may need some logic on refresh to check the list box/select box and if option X is selected, then make field X visible.  not sure this is what you need...

Comment: that might work, any clue onto how to do that?

like how to make a verification on page load

and thanks a million on your fast replies

Comment: I dont' have exp. with php or forms, but can you access the verification response via javascript or php after page refresh?  or maybe thinking to hard and just a simple body onload function to check selected options is all that is needed.

Comment: I think augie is right. As for verification on page load, just run a function with the `onLoad` event that checks for fields with text in them (or whatever other verification condition you want to use) and sets the appropriate style attribute for that field to make it visible.

Comment: thanks guys you putted me on a track and made me remember a function i used for a scrollto()